# Start Driver When Graphics Tablet is Connected

Tags: usb, startup, autostart

I have this veik-tablet app installed on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 system. I must start it first and it opens minimized at system tray only after that I'm able to use my tablet.

But I want the app to start automatically as soon as the tablet connected via usb, is that possible?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? A must read is https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it might be possible, look into udev rules

Comment: @David sorry, now added to the post, 22.04.1

Comment: @Esther will check out, thank you!